# Linux tail command includes more lines than intended

Tags: linux, tail

so I want to get a little into Linux scripting and started by a simple example in a book. In this book, the author wants me to grab the five lines before "Step #6: Configure output plugins" from snort.conf.

Analogous to the author I  determined where the line is that I want, which returns 445 for me. If I then use tail the result returns more text than I expect and the searched line that should be in line 5 is at line 88. I fail to understand how I use the tail command and start at the specific line but then more text is included.

To search for the line I used

```
nl /etc/snort/snort.conf | grep output.
```

To get the 5 lines before including the searched line:

```
tail -n+440 /etc/snort/snort.conf | head -n+6
```

where as the tail statement seems to be the problem. Any help is appreciated on why my answer is not working!

Comment: There are simpler ways to do what you're doing, but the command you gave *should* output lines 440 through 445.

Comment: Okay, so if command 2 does what I intend to the first command must return something wrong, right? I would copy paste my console but I use a VM...

Comment: Just for comparison: try `grep -n 'Configure output plugins' /etc/snort/snort.conf` to find the line number, and `sed -n 440,445p /etc/snort/snort.conf` to extract those lines, and to combine them in a single step `grep -B 5 'Configure output plugins' /etc/snort/snort.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tail` command is correct in principle.

The problem lies in the way in which you acquire the line number using `nl`. The `nl` command does not count empty lines by default, while the `tail` command does. You should specify in your `nl` command that you want to count the empty lines as well, which you can do using the `-b`, (body-numbering) option and specify `a` as your style. This would look as follows:

```
nl -ba /etc/snort/snort.conf | grep output.
```

From `nl --help`:

> ```
> Usage: nl [OPTION]... [FILE]...
> Write each FILE to standard output, with line numbers added.
>
> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
>
> Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
>   -b, --body-numbering=STYLE      use STYLE for numbering body lines
>
> [...]
>
> By default, selects -v1 -i1 -l1 -sTAB -w6 -nrn -hn -bt -fn.  CC are
> two delimiter characters for separating logical pages, a missing
> second character implies :.  Type \\ for \.  STYLE is one of:
>
>   a         number all lines
>   t         number only nonempty lines
> ```

Number all lines and use that line number in `tail`.

Comment: And I just assumed `nl` would be the same as `cat -n` that I always use. Good catch

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you! As I said Im new to pretty much everything so I didnt even think about using --help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello in trying the same with same book that you are using but I didn’t find any great solution with tail or nl but i come up with simple grep switch -B and -A before and after switches for grep.

I achieved this issue by typing

grep -B 5 “Step #6: Configure output plugins “ /etc/snort/snort.conf

After that you will gonna get 5 lines before that line same for After -A for after lines.

Hope this will help someone staysafe happy learning

Comment: Thanks for the comment!